# Subjectivity clustering process

Tags: clustering

While studying about clustering (newbie to the field) I have seen many times the term 'Subjectivity'. Can someone explain me what exactly this term means? is Subjectivity always present in the clustering process?

Answer (score 0):

There is no *objective* definition of a cluster that people would agree on.

Everybody uses a different, *subjective* understanding of what is a cluster.

C.f. Estivill-Castro, Vladimir. "Why so many clustering algorithms: a position paper." ACM SIGKDD explorations newsletter 4.1 (2002): 65-75.